# Symfony: How to access user in KernelEvents::EXCEPTION event handler?

Tags: symfony

I am using `Symfony 3.4` and have create a `EventSubscriber` for `KernelEvents::EXCEPTION`.

How can I access the current user in the event handler? I am using the following code but it returns `null` / `annon.` for the user. I assume that the event is fired before the login process is handled.

```
class SecurityEventsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    ...

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => array(array('onKernelException', 0)),
        );
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event) {
        $user = null
        if ($this->securityContext->getToken() && $this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            $exception = $event->getException();
            if ($exception instanceof HttpException && $exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {               
               // Send message to user...
            }
        } else {
            // Always executed since $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser() return 'annon.'
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any solution to access the current user in this event handler?

**EDIT:**

I would like to monitor if there are user accounts with an unusual high number of not_found, method_not_allowed, etc. errors to prevent possible attacks. Monitoring these exception is no problem but how do I get the corresponding user account?

Comment: The [exception event](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-exception) is only fired after an exception is raised.  So of course if an exception is thrown before the security listener does it's job then you won't have access to the user.  But if, for example, a controller action does the throwing then you code should work assuming the security context has been injected.

Comment: Yes, this is what I assumed. The question is, if there is anything to access the user anyway. For example trigger the login handling manually, etc.?

Comment: If you are already in a failure state before the authentication is triggered, you could possibly move whatever code it was, that raised the excepion, e.g. some early listener, to after the FirewallListener was called. Any other approach I can think of e.g. manually fetching the Session data or triggering the authentication sounds like a security nightmare. From what it looks like you want to "hide" some failures by showing a 404 page, similar to how Github does it. Why not always show a 404 unconditionally and log the actual error, so you can fix the underlying issue?

Comment: I would like to monitor if there are user accounts with an unusual high number of not_found, method_not_allowed, etc. errors to prevent possible attacks. Monitoring these exception is no problem but how do I get the corresponding user account?