Symfony 7.0 - Can't get user details in Event Listener
I use Symfony 7.0 framework. I got stuck with this for a few days. Googled, used AI chat, read documentation, but nothing helped.
I can't get use details inside of my Event Listener class from Security component. This code:
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Attribute\AsEventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security;

final class ExceptionListener extends AbstractController
{
    public function __construct( 
        protected Security $security, 
    )
    {
    }

    #[AsEventListener(event: KernelEvents::EXCEPTION)]
    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event): void
    {
        // Getting exception from ExceptionEvent object
        $exception = $event->getThrowable();

        // Getting current user
        $user = $this->security->getUser();
        die(var_export($user));

        // Provera da li je izuzetak tipa NotFoundHttpException
        if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            // Odredjivanje template-a u zavisnosti od uloge korisnika
            $template = 'error404_user.html.twig'; // Default template za ulogovane korisnike
            $roles = [];

            // Provera da li je korisnik prijavljen i koje uloge ima
            if ($user) {
                $roles = $user->getRoles();
                if (in_array('ROLE_ADMIN', $roles)) {
                    $template = 'error404_admin.html.twig'; // Template za admina
                }
            }

            // Generisanje odgovora sa odgovarajućim template-om
            $response = new Response();
            $response->setContent(
                $this->render($template, ['exception' => $exception, 'roles' => $roles])->getContent()
            );

            // Postavljanje HTTP status koda na 404
            $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);

            // Postavljanje odgovora u ExceptionEvent objekat
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}

This is service.yaml code:
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-parameters-for-application-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
        tags: [kernel.event_listener]

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones

die(var_export($user)); always backs NULL.

I want to get user details inside of event listener. Depending of user role, the user should be redirected to an appropriate page. Can someone help me with this?

Have you checked your event listener priority and symfony authentication priority ? It's possible your event listener is triggered before symfony handle your user authentication

@DylanKAS I'm still learning Symfony., so I don't know what is authentication priority. How can I check that?

php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher

@DylanKAS php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.exception should for my listener. Am I correct? Which is for checking authentication priority?

It's a bit tricky with an ExceptionListener because it may be called before the security listener act. You may find a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582590/symfony-how-to-access-user-in-kerneleventsexception-event-handler (sadly lacking a proper answer).

And you should take a look here: https://dev.to/aelamel/symfony-empty-token-storage-when-injecting-service-in-an-event-listener-4fh7

Side note, it's odd that your event listener extends AbstractController. Event listeners are not controllers -- typically just simple services. It's unlikely that this is related to your issue but still worth pointing out.

@AdamRichard Yes, you are right, but I need render() method.
